# Polymer iron-form not working

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have the following markup in my html:

```
<form is="iron-form" login-form>
    <paper-input label="Email" type="email" name="email"></paper-input>
    <paper-input label="Password" type="password" name="password"></paper-input>
    <paper-button class="self-end btn-primary" raised login-btn>Login</paper-button>
</form>
```

In chrome, the form is never upgraded to an iron-form, but it works fine in firefox.  However, I can use: `document.createElement('form', 'iron-form');` to create an iron-form that is properly upgraded.
This is driving me crazy.  Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: That snippet looks correct, I suspect the issue is elsewhere.  Can you post the complete page containing that form?

Comment: @Zikes, my html is being rendered dynamically using meteor (blaze).  The element is being imported properly because it works in firefox and I can imperatively create `iron-form`s prior to the time that my actual template containing the `iron-form` is rendered.  I have also tried including an `iron-input` in my template to test if it was an issue extending base elements.  Both elements use the `is` attribute, but the `iron-input` works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why the `iron-input` should work any differently. Are you sure the iron-input is working perfectly *as a Polymer element* when you create it in the template? (For example, does it have the utility functions like `debounce`?) I ask because it looks like a standard input.

Looking at the Meteor code, it doesn't look like **any** type-extension elements should work. As far as I can tell, it looks like all tag creation goes through here:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/832e6fe44f3635cae060415d6150c0105f2bf0f6/packages/blaze/materializer.js#L99

To handle type-extension custom elements, I think this needs another branch that does something like:

```
} else if (tag.attrs && ('is' in tag.attrs)) {
  // type-extension custom element
  elem = document.createElement(tagName, tag.attrs[is]);     
} else {
  // normal elements
  elem = document.createElement(tagName);
}
```

The two-arg `createElement` will only work if you have native custom element support or you have the polyfill installed, so Meteor might want to handle this another way.

Comment: Yep, had to dig in and came to the same conclusion.  Haha, thanks!

Comment: Related question.. Appreciate if you can help on this - how to make meteor handle this? https://forums.meteor.com/t/support-for-polymers-is-iron-form-attribute/6309